# upload multiple files using the same uploader angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i'm trying to get this uploader working, This is what i have at the moment

This is my html

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="row in fileUploadRows">
                    <div ng-if="advanced_user" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" style="display:inline-block" ngf-select="uploadinv($file, $index)">Upload Attachment</div>
                    <p style="display:inline-block;" ng-if="row.fileName">Uploaded file: {{row.fileName}}
                        <button type="button" ng-click="deleteInvAttachment(event.filenameinv)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" ng-click="addInvAttachment($index)" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" ng-click="removeInvAttachment(row)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                            remove last attachment
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

And this is in my controller

```
$scope.fileUploadRows = [];
var fileDetails = {
  fileName: $scope.event.filenameinv
}

$scope.fileUploadRows.push(fileDetails);

$scope.counter = 1;

$scope.addInvAttachment = function(index) {
  var fileDetails = {
    fileName: ''
  }
  $scope.fileUploadRows.push(fileDetails);
  $scope.counter++;
}

$scope.removeInvAttachment = function(row) {
  $scope.fileUploadRows.splice(row, 1);
}
```

Now what I've got at the moment works to an extent, I can click the plus button and it'll load a blank upload button on the html side, As well as a blank fileName in the `{{fileUploadRows}}` Now the issue i have is when i try and upload a new file. It replaces the old file (as well as the old string etc)

Heres my uploader

```
$scope.uploadinv = function (file, index) {
        if (file && $scope.advanced_user) {
            Upload.upload({
                url: '',
                data: {file: file}
            }).then(function (resp) {
                sweetAlert({title: "Attachment Saved", type: "success"});
            }, function (resp) {
                sweetAlert({title: "Attachment Not Saved", type: "error"});
            }, function (evt) {
                var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
                $scope.event.filenameinv = evt.config.data.file.name
            });
        }
    };
```

So how would i go about saving each file into the array?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I **strongly** recommend you to use ng-file-upload : https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Very complete, supports drag and drop, image resizing, and many more.

It seems you might be using it (i noticed Upload service and the ngf-select directive)

If you are, check out ngf-change, and try binding your file input with ng-model, for $scope accessibility.